# webpage (app) layout - set 100% height (html, css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I'm having a HUGE problem, geting my masterpage layout to stretch to 100% browser window height. There is no problem for width. I tried many different solutions, but none worked.

This is what I have so far. I managed to expand html and body to height:100%, but div#container is giving me problems...it wont expand to height:100%. For testing purposes I put borders arround html, body and container, to see which one isn't working. Any help appritiated. I'm designing my web app in VS2010 and using Chrome (also tested in IE and Mozilla with no success).

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="headercontent">
                HEADER
            </div>
            <div id="leftcontent">
                <p>LEFT CONTENT</p>
                <p>MENU</p>
                <p>MENU</p>
                <p>MENU</p>
            </div>
            <div id="rightcontent">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div id="footercontent">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my stylesheet.css

```
body{
    font-family: "Lucida Grande" , "Lucida Sans Unicode" , Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: yellow;
}

html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    line-height:150%;
}

#headercontent{
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
   clear: left;
}

#leftcontent{
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
   margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

#rightcontent{
    margin-left: 190px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
}

#footercontent{
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: I retagged your question adding JQuery, Javascript and html because many solutions are also available using these technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body element IS 100% height as you set it but you've not set the contents to anything to position anywhere so they follow the normal flow, like a stack of boxes, as they should. You also don't have enough content to fill the screen. If you want the footer to stick to the bottom, search here on SO or Google for "sticky footer".

If you want some of the content to stretch further, you'll have to add some height to those.

Comment: I did look for sticky footer and managed to make it work. Only problem I have now is, how to stretch the content to be always 100% height (min is 100% AND max is 100%). any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

Set html and body to `height: 100%;`:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Next step: wrap your form with a container and gibt it a minimum height of 100%:

```
#wrapper { 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

This won't work in IE6. Therefor add a little hack:

```
* html #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thnx, but it is not working :( I tried so many things (divs, table, divs+table), none worked. It's really pissing me off. Can't figure why...

Comment: the thing is...if I try the same code in w3schools "emulator" everything stretches perfectly...but when I start it in my browser it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `#container` element is nested inside your `<form>` tag, so even though you've set the height of `#container` to 100%, this will set it's height to 100% of it's parent element i.e. the `<form>` tag.

Try moving your `#container <div>` tag so it sits outside the `<form>` tag like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/E4zAm/

Comment: I did the floating footer solution, but it didn't work until I moved my form tag (I needed it on the masterpage, because there is a dropdownlist, so I couldn't just remove it). Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with having div#container using position: absolute, you can use this little trick:

```
#container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    line-height:150%;
}
```

Setting all four layout attributes (top/right/bottom/left) to the values you want will cause the element to stretch to accomodate those values.

Comment: that is an option. but the reason why I want percentages is because it will be used on many diferent resolutions and screen sizes, so I want it to be flexible. :/ I'll go mad. I tried almost any solution I found with google, none worked.